# How to make a reconnection with socket

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio

I am trying to do a routine for reconnection with socket without success.
When I stop and restart server, the client closes the connection, but I can not reset it. Any suggestion?

This is a sample:

```
private void StartSocket(String IP, String port) {
    execsocket = true;
    st = new SocketTask(IP, Integer.parseInt(port), 5000) {
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            recived = subst_emoticon(progress[0]);
            Log.d("Rec", recived);
            String cmd = "";
            if (!recived.isEmpty()) {
                if (recived.length() >= 4) {
                    cmd = recived.substring(0, 4);
                }

                if (cmd.equals("ERRO")) {
                    String[] parts = recived.split(";");
                    if (parts[0].equals("ERROR1")) {
                        if (!Repetir) {
                            if (MsgBox("No connection", "Working in offline?", "No", "Yes")) {
                                offline = true;
                                IP = "0";
                                Send("!LOG;" + Usuario + ";" + Senha);
                            } else
                                finish();
                        } 
                    }

                    if (parts[0].equals("ERROR2")) {
                        if (MsgBox("Lost connection", "Retry?", "No", "Yes")) {
                        **//Routine for retry connection //**       
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks!!